# Send zip file from node.js server to node.js client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, zip

I am trying to send a zip file from a node.js server to a node.js client but when i save the zip it is corrupted and will not open.

I am using adm-zip to zip the file and send to client

```
app.get('/checkForUpdate', function (req, res) {

    var zip = new AdmZip();
    zip.addLocalFile("./update.js");
    var willSendthis = zip.toBuffer();
    res.send(willSendthis);

});
```

here is my client code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {version: version},
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/checkForUpdate',
    success: function (data) {

        fs.writeFile("update.zip", data, function(err) {

            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("The file was saved!");
            }

        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should be set for MIME type `application/x-zip-compressed`.

Comment: Try these : `application/zip, application/octet-stream`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is sending a buffer. If I remember right a buffer needs a mime type of octect-stream. Try using octect-stream in the header and have adm-zip load the buffer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compress a text or any data as a zip file you can use JSZip npm package.

I have given the link below to install it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jszip

The code below converts the text file and sends it as a buffer that the client can download.

```
const zip = new JSZip()
zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n")
const buffer = await zip.generateAsync({ type: `nodebuffer` })
res.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': `application/zip` })
res.end(buffer)
```